# Why are all the analyzers on a new .NET5 project suppressed?

Tags: code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis, .net-5

I just updated a project to use .NET5 on the latest VS2019, and given that the .NET analyzers are now part of .NET5, I reverted to using those.. except they're all suppressed. The CA1062 rule for example, is listed as having a severity of 'Warning', but an 'Effective Severity' of 'Suppressed', and I can't find any way of getting it to work.

I don't have an editor config or anything like that, even on a brand new project it does the same. I've searched as much as I can, but I can't find anywhere that might give me some clue as to why this is happening.

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try setting

```
    <AnalysisMode>AllEnabledByDefault</AnalysisMode>
```

in your .csproj file. See [AnalysisMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#analysismode)

Comment: That.. worked perfectly, and I'm now cursing MS for failing to put the ability to set this into the project properties page.

Comment: @Flynn1179 Be glad. For .NET Framework projects the property page displays deprecated Code Analysis settings.